Normalization of the SYK Hamiltonian: Why the energy $E$ is proportional to $N$?
In the usual SYK model described via
$$
H = -\frac{1}{N^{3/2}}\sum_{ijkl}^{N}J_{ij,kl}\psi_{i}\psi_{j}\psi_{k}\psi_{l}.
$$
The normalization factor out front ($N^{-3/2}$) is chosen such that the energy is extensive, i.e. $$E \sim O(N).$$
However, I am a little confused as to how the above quantity scales like $N$. Since the sum is over four seperate variables that each range through $N$, shouldn't the sum scale like $N^{4}$? And, if so, then how is the $N^{-3/2}$ prefactor sufficient to make $H$ scale like $N$? I don't see any reason why the couplings themselves would depend on or scale with the system size, so I would think that the prefactor would have to be $N^{-3}$? Or is it just implicitly assumed that $J \sim N^{-3/2}$?

Could you provide a reference for this way of writing the Hamiltonian? I'm more familiar with the original way proposed by Kitaev, in which the prefactor is $1/4!$ and the variance is taken to be $\overline{J^2_{ijkl}} \propto \frac{J^2}{N^{-3}}$.

@Anyon Sure--see appendix A of https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.03924. I've also seen it defined this way in some of Subir's papers, for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05246

Reference to the statement that the energy is extensive?

That the energy is extensive $E\sim N$ can e.g. be seen using [1]

The free Euclidean Lagrangian of $N$ Majorana fermions is
$$ L_0(\tau)~=~\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N\psi^i(\tau)\partial_{\tau}\psi^i(\tau).\tag{108}$$

The Hamiltonian is
$$H(\tau)~=~ \frac{i^{q/2}}{q!}\sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_q=1}^N\underbrace{\frac{J_{i_1\ldots i_q}}{N^{\frac{q-1}{2}}}}_{=:\widetilde{J}_{i_1\ldots i_q}}\psi^{i_1}(\tau)\ldots\psi^{i_q}(\tau),\tag{93+94}$$
where $q\in 2\mathbb{N}$. The imaginary factors ensures that $H$ is Hermitian. Concerning the normalization, see also this related Phys.SE post.

Average the partition function wrt. a Gaussian ensemble
$$ \langle J_{i_1\ldots i_q}J_{j_1\ldots j_q}\rangle_{\psi=0}~=~ (q\!-\!1)!J^2 \sum_{\pi\in S_q}(-1)^{\sigma(\pi)}\delta_{i_1,j_{\pi(1)}}\ldots\delta_{i_q,j_{\pi(q)}}.\tag{101}$$

Equivalently, introduce a Gaussian term in the Euclidean action
$$\begin{align}S[\psi,J]~=~&\int\! d\tau~[L_0(\tau) + H(\tau)] \cr
~+~&\frac{1}{2J^2(q\!-\!1)!}\sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_q=1}^N \sum_{\pi\in S_q}(-1)^{\sigma(\pi)}J_{i_1\ldots i_q}J_{i_{\pi(1)}\ldots i_{\pi(q)}}.\end{align} \tag{109}$$

Completing the square produces a bi-local Hamiltonian density $${\cal H}(\tau,\tau^{\prime})~=~\frac{(-1)^{q/2}}{2q}\underbrace{\frac{J^2}{N^{q-1}}}_{=:\widetilde{J}^2}\sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_q=1}^N\psi^{i_1}(\tau)\ldots\psi^{i_q}(\tau)\psi^{i_1}(\tau^{\prime})\ldots\psi^{i_q}(\tau^{\prime})\tag{110}$$
inside a bi-local Euclidean Lagrangian density: $$ {\cal L}(\tau,\tau^{\prime})~=~\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime})L_0(\tau)-{\cal H}(\tau,\tau^{\prime}).\tag{110}$$

Introduce a bi-local master field
$$G(\tau,\tau^{\prime})
~\approx~\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\psi_i(\tau)\psi_i(\tau^{\prime}).\tag{112}$$

The bi-local Hamiltonian density becomes
$${\cal H}(\tau,\tau^{\prime})
~\approx~ \frac{NJ^2}{2q} G(\tau,\tau^{\prime})^q\tag{113}$$
(up to a constraint times a Lagrange multiplier $\Sigma$). The bi-local field $G$ is intensive wrt. $N$, so ${\cal H}\sim N$ is extensive. $\Box$


References:

G. Sarosi, $AdS_2$ holography and the SYK model, arXiv:1711.08482.

