How do I see that the different definitions for the SYK Hamiltonian are equivalent?
I'm excited to better understand the holography within the SYK model. I enjoy a rigorous understanding, which I'm trying to achieve via the 'review' papers from Rosenhaus, Maldacena, Trunin and Sarosi.
Question:
I am quite stuck and it boils down to understanding how the different definitions for the SYK Hamiltonians agree:
$$H^{(1)}_\text{SYK}=\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^NJ_{ijkl}\psi_i\psi_j\psi_k\psi_l,\tag1$$ $$
H^{(2)}_\text{SYK}=\frac{1}{4!}\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^NJ_{ijkl}\psi_i\psi_j\psi_k\psi_l,\tag2$$ $$
H_\text{SYK}^{(3)}=\sum_{1\leq i<j<k<l\leq N}J_{ijkl}\psi_i\psi_j\psi_k\psi_l.\tag3$$
(1) is used in Sarosi (93); (2) in Rosenhaus (2.8) & Trunin (3.1); (3) in Maldacena (2.2). Here $$\{\psi_n,\psi_m\}=\delta_{nm}.$$
I tried: It is claimed the coupling $J_{ijkl}$ is totally anti-symmetric (given the anti-commutation relation/Clifford algebra). Using this, I can show definitions (2) and (3) are equivalent except for terms in (2) that have terms like $\psi_i\psi_j\psi_k\psi_k=\psi_i\psi_j/2$ which is formally allowed the way the notation is denoted (here I used that $\psi_n^2=1/2$ via the algebra). Do I need to understand the summation in (2) to have $i\neq j\neq k\neq l$? If so, this seems to conflict with equations in Trunin (such as on p12 and p13). I don't see how (1) and (2) are the same: they don't even generate the same Euler-Lagrange equations.
Additionally, I cannot convince myself $J_{ijkl}$ is anti-symmetric. What I did was
$$J_{2134}\psi_2\psi_1\psi_3\psi_4=-J_{2134}\psi_1\psi_2\psi_3\psi_4:=J_{1234}\psi_1\psi_2\psi_3\psi_4,$$
where the last step is done on physical grounds 'the number in front of $\psi_1\psi_2\psi_3\psi_4$ should be the same in all cases since the interaction strength is the same between the fields'. But this doesn't make any sense: I could equally well just add them up $$J_{1234}/N-J_{2134}/N+...:=J^\text{eff}_{1234}.$$ Doing this procedure for all fermions gets me from definition (2) to (3) and $J^\text{eff}_{ijkl}$ is anti-symmetric, but $J_{ijkl}$ is not.

Isn't it just imposed by fiat that $J_{ijkl}$ is antisymmetric?

I think this makes most sense, but I would be worried: Trunin on p10 says 'anticommutation relations (3.2) imply the antisymmetry of the couplings'. I'm hesitant to say experts are wrong.


In the operator formalism there is an implicitly written normal ordering of the 4-fermion term. The fermions anticommute under the normal order symbol.

In the path integral formulation, the fermions also anticommute in the action.

The symmetric group $S_4$ acts on the 4 indices of the coupling constants $J_{ijkl}$, thereby establishing a group representation. We can decompose $J_{ijkl}$ according to irreducible representations (irreps) of $S_4$. The anticommuting fermions annihilate all but the sign representation, which has Young tableau
$$\begin{array}{c} [~~]\cr [~~] \cr [~~]\cr [~~]\end{array}.$$
(All other Young tableaux for irreps of $S_4$ have a row with at least 2 elements, which correspond to symmetric indices.)

Equivalently, we may assume from the onset that the coupling constants $J_{ijkl}$ are totally antisymmetric.

With assumption 4, the normal order symbol is superfluous.

It follows that $\frac{1}{4!}H^{(1)}_\text{SYK}=H^{(2)}_\text{SYK}=H^{(3)}_\text{SYK}.$




Could you please elaborate on why 3. holds? 2. Additionally, this does not solve my confusion with the summation (do I need to assume $i\neq j\neq k\neq l$?)



I updated the answer.


Thank you. 1. I see there are empty brackets, was that your intention? 2. Anyhow, I still do not fully understand how irreps of the permutation group are involved with decompositions of the coupling. It does seem extremely interesting: are there any sources you could recommend?

1+2. I updated the answer.

More on SYK normalization: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/823343/2451
